# meta box for header

Tags: wordpress

I actually searched on the web about meta boxes but didnt find the thing I want since they were page and post specific .  So I am actually searching for a thing(meta box or whatever) which will  provide me a simple text field in the admin panel and when I enter the link of the youtube video and hit submit the video would appear in the HEADER of my blog . So which tool will let me to do the thing I described ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually "custom fields" what I  meant here . For each post you can add a custom field and in the header you can use each's  value via 'get_post_custom_values'  function .